# Unable to add corporate account with same email address as google account on Lollipop

Tags: google-account, exchange, accounts, 5.0-lollipop

Just upgraded my Nexus 5 to Lollipop and have bumped into a serious issue with account management.

I have my Google account registered to a non-gmail domain, and use Exchange Online to host it. Up to Kit-kat, this presented no particular issue: I would  log in to Google’s services using my Google account and then add a corporate account to handle email.

Lollipop prevents me from doing so however: whenever I try to add the corporate account I get an error message saying the account I’m trying to create is a duplicate (this happens at the very first screen, when the only available field is the account’s email address - which of course is going to be the same).

Has somebody found a way around this? If not, what is the best way to submit a bug report, since the Gmail App is not part of AOSP?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around this by putting in an invalid email address on the first step (e.g. myname@mydomain.com.exchange) then clicking the button to set up the account manually. I wanted to set up an Exchange account and was able to enter my proper corporate credentials in the following steps. This seems to have worked.